# Show popup at the start if file is missing

Tags: java, swing, popup, jframe, program-entry-point

I am creating a small GUI java application that it will store some user credentials in a file.

If the file is missing or has the wrong properties then I want a pop to get brought up that will inform the user to register his credentials (so a new file can be created with the proper ones).

I have nailed down the logic of when the file is incorrect and/or missing but what I can't figure out (due to my inexperience with JFrame) is where exactly in the code to check if the user needs to enter his credentials so he can be prompted.

Let's say that the function `showWarning()` is the one that will check and display the popup if needed and this is my `main` JFrame function (this was generated from Netbeans mostly):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
  });
}
```

Do I put the `showWarning()` function inside the `main` function? If yes, do I put it right after `new GUI().setVisible(true);`? What is the proper way of doing this?

EDIT: I am stumbling to the same problem I did before. This is my `showWarning()` that I drafted quickly for testing purposes:

```
public void showWarning(){
        File propertiesFile = new File("config.properties");
        if (propertiesFile.exists() && propertiesExist(propertiesFile)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Creds are ok");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Creds are not ok");
        }
    }
```

The problem that I am having is that I can't make this method static in order to use it without an object because of the `rootPane` which is a non-static object. The problem that this caused is that I can't just write:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
                showWarning();
        }
  });
}
```

I can't use `showWarning()` like that since it's a non-static method.

Do I need to have the `GUI` object in a variable properly or is there a way to make the `showWarning()` a static method?

Comment: So you want the check to run right away correct?

Comment: @Kyle yes, it will run once at startup.

Comment: Ok then my answer should be enough to get you started. Unless you are trying to do the code to make the popup in that spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the check to run right when the program starts, you would want to put your function call after the main JFrame gui is set visible. See edited code below. Of course, I'm using the ambiguous showWarning() function here, but you should talor that line of code to your need. If calling a function, then right the function, but if wanting to call a new popup jframe you will need to do more lines of code there.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
                LoginForm login = new LoginForm();
                login.setVisible(true);
        }
  });
}
```

Now here you would want to change the variables accordingly. The LoginForm is a Jframe already created.

Comment: I have added in the post what specific problem comes up if I do what you say.

Comment: Shouldn't `final Main mainframe = new Main();` be `final GUI mainframe = new GUI();` and then I can skip the `new GUI().setVisible(true);` above all together? Shouldn't I just make an object `final GUI mainframe = new GUI();` and then call `mainframe.setVisible(true);` and `mainframe.showWarning();`

Comment: Ok I've edited the code again and it should work for you, you just need to change the variables accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want your popup dialog to be modal, so the program does not continue until the user has handled and fixed the problem. To do this, do not use a JFrame but a JDialog for your popup dialog and make it modal. Then you can simply put the `showWarning()` call everywhere you want. I think I would put it inside the main.

Comment: What I plan on doing is show a popup like "User Credentials are missing, please enter your credentials" and when he hits "OK" a panel will show in which he will fill the credentials and as soon as he hits save, this panel will close and another will open with the main program. That's what I would ideally want to do but if I cannot find how to do it I will just show him a popup.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JDialog` for creating the pop up.
And either you add the `showWarning()` method call in main like this :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
                showWarning();
        }
  });
}
```

or better you can invoke the method `showWarning()` when the user credentials have to be enetered in the file. If checked just before it, it would be optimal.